# Unknown Prop with React, how to create new html property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I am trying to create an `:indeterminate` property on my input element for my radio and checkbox.

I have the following error thrown by react :

```
Unknown prop `indeterminate` on <input> tag. Remove this prop from the element
```

Is it possible to create new prop or is it completely locked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply wrap the input into another component that can accept the `indeterminate` prop:

```
const IndeterminateInput = React.createClass({
  render() {
    // Create props clone
    const cleanProps = Object.assign({}, this.props);
    delete cleanProps['indeterminate'];
    return <input ref="input" {...cleanProps}/>
  },
  updateInput: function () {
    this.refs.input.indeterminate = Boolean(this.props.indeterminate);
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    // Initial render
    this.updateInput();
  },
  componentDidUpdate() {
    // Props change
    this.updateInput();    
  } 
});
```

Then you can use this component as a wrapper:

```
<IndeterminateInput type="checkbox" indeterminate />
```

Notice that even in HTML `indeterminate` is not a valid attribute. You have to update the DOM manually:

```
<!-- This does not work! -->
<input type="checkbox" indeterminate>
```